How can i create an event after a redirection with htmx?
If I have a code snippet like this::
response = HttpResponse(status=204)
response["HX-Redirect"] = request.build_absolute_uri('/perfil/')
response['HX-Trigger'] = 'useredited'
return response

How can I capture the 'useredited' event after the redirection occurs? When I try, the event is triggered before the redirection. Thanks for your help!

You can't, once the redirection happens in the browser, any custom events are cleared. What is the reason for firing this event after redirection?

Thanks for the response. I want to update the screen with the new user value and display a message confirming that everything worked fine, but I have to approach it differently.

You can just use django's messages module and add new success message right  after user entry is created, then render it somewhere in the template. After redirection django will show the proper content, it's just a matter of styling it.
